# Visual Studio 2013 restarting on adding data source to listview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to add a new data source to my listview (which I have added to my asp.net page). But when I connect to .\SQLEXPRESS, choose the required database and click OK, visual studio 2013 restarts (message displayed is Visual Studio has stopped working). I had clicked on test connection before clicking OK and it was showing successful. What can be the problem? Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Did you try updating Visual Studio with the latest update 4 for visual studio?

Comment: I have already updated but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the SQL Extension or use visual studio express.

Comment: I tried updating SQL Extension but no help. Using visual studio express I was able to add datasource to the listview

Answer (score 0):

Use VS as administrator

1.Right-click devenv.exe

2.Select Run as administrator

Comment: I tried running devenv.exe as administrator but no success.